# What is the reasoning of this SQL syntax

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement where I check a column to make sure the word 'call' is not there like this:

```
 select * from TableName where PFSeat <> 'call'
```

But this statement will not include records where PFSeat is Null. In order to get all the records I need I have to change the statement to look like this

```
 select * from TableName where (PFSeat <> 'call' OR PFSeat Is Null)
```

Is there a reason why it is coded to where I dont get all the records I need from the first statement? What is the reason?

Comment: Not all DBMS are created equal. Oracle, for example, does not return `null` with a `<>`

Comment: The reason is that `null` is a very special non-value that can't be compared using `=` or `<>`. This is how SQL was defined 30 years ago. But you can simplify the condition to `where PFSeat is distinct from 'call'`

Comment: By definition any operator other than IS NULL used with a NULL value is FALSE. And Oracle is not an exception to this rule.

Comment: @Jonast92 That doesn't explain why `WHERE Column <> 'Value'` doesn't include `NULL` values.

Comment: Not any dbms should evaluate `<> null` as true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (and should) read the first statement as "all rows where `PFSeat` has a value, and that value is not `'call'`".
It results from a choice made several decades ago that `NULL` is *not a value, but the absence of a value*. Most if not all DBMS adhere to that rule, otherwise many queries would start producing unexpected results.

So `NULL` is not a value, it is a property meaning that no value is present.
Many clauses in SQL where any part or parameter is `NULL` will produce `NULL`, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SQL not displaying null values on a not equals query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036691/sql-not-displaying-null-values-on-a-not-equals-query) . When comparing a record with PFSeat set to NULL using `PFSeat <> 'call'` the result is not TRUE. The result is NULL and so you do not see those records. @PeterB is right this is because NULL is not a value.

Also have a look at [Why NULL never compares false to anything in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/)