# IN , NOT IN for null value in oracle

Tags: oracle, notin

In oracle why "Not in" doesn't work on null values but "IN" works 
For eg

```
  with temp(n,p) as (
  select 1,2 from dual union all
  select 3,2 from dual union all
  select 4,6 from dual union all
  select 5,6 from dual union all
  select 2,8 from dual union all
  select 6,8 from dual union all
  select 8,null from dual
  )
1. Select * from temp where n in (2,6,8,null);
2. Select * from temp where n not in (2,6,8,null);
```

First Statement will give the output = 2,6,8
Second statement will not give any output

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: It works, as it should. What outcome do you expect?

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL not displaying null values on a not equals query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036691/sql-not-displaying-null-values-on-a-not-equals-query)

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` essentially works like this:

```
col NOT IN (value_a, value_b, value_c)
-- is the same as
col != value_a && col != value_b && col != value_c
```

If one of the values is `null`, the whole expression evaluates to `null`, not `true` (which you probably expect).

You can read more about it here: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/not-in/